# How many Jedi and Sith Holocrons did Palpatine have?

Tags: star-wars

Does anyone know how many Jedi and Sith Holocrons Emperor Palpatine had? Was he able to open the Jedi Holocrons and what if anything did they teach him?

Comment: He had direct access to the Jedi vaults so it's reasonable to assume that he had loads. Depending on the source, Palpatine was either blocked from accessing them entirely or could [only scratch the surface of their knowledge](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=esFJBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT384&lpg=PT384&dq=palpatine+jedi+holocrons&source=bl&ots=p8jEtBlMWL&sig=ACfU3U2OAm46dTgbdMi6TJATTABYAxmhJA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3nMHD1IrpAhW-RxUIHSOuA8gQ6AEwGXoECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=jedi%20holocrons&f=false)